# How can I find the translated co-ordinates of an SVG element?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I have a SVG element with `x` and `y` set, but I'm also translating it by a certain vector using `transform="translate(a, b)"`, which changes the co-ordinates it's rendered to but obviously doesn't update its `x` and `y` attributes. Is there a way to get the actual co-ordinates, which in this case would be `x + a` and `y + b`, without having to directly parse the values out of the `transform` attribute?

Not that this is a D3-specific question, but my code looks like this:

```
svg.selectAll(selector)
    .attr("x", x)
    .attr("y", y)
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .attr("transform", `translate(${a}, ${b})`);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, this is not really D3 related, but pure SVG/javascript:

I use this function here that I call "flatten", basically you want to reset matrix to non-transformed one (matrix(1 0 0 1 0 0)) and update path points with their sort of flattened values:

```
flattenShape(item, matrix) {
    let points = item.pathPoints;
    let l = points.length;
    for (let i = 0; i<l; i++) {
        let cache = this.mainSVG.createSVGPoint();
        cache.x = points[i].x;
        cache.y = points[i].y;
        cache = cache.matrixTransform(matrix);
        points[i].x = cache.x;
        points[i].y = cache.y;
    }
    item.d = this.constructPath(points);
    item.transform = "matrix(1 0 0 1 0 0)";
};
```

`item` - your SVG element, `matrix` - you need to get the actual `SVGMatrix` of the element in question. I get it using:

```
let matrix = YOUR_SVG_ELEMENT.transform.baseVal.consolidate().matrix;
```

So my approach is maybe too specific but generally speaking:

- consolidate matrix of the SVG element that you are transforming.
- use SVGPoint to perform: matrixTransform(matrix) for each coordinate in question.
- reset transform attribute to initial state e.g. matrixTransform(matrix)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `getBoundingClientRect()` method to get the **position** of the node.

Here's a snippet showing two `rect`s with one of them ***translated***:

```js
var svgXY = d3.select('svg').node().getBoundingClientRect();

var rect1 = d3.select('rect#test1').node().getBoundingClientRect();
console.log('Rect 1: { top: ' + (rect1.top-svgXY.top) + ', left: ' + (rect1.left-svgXY.left) + '}');

var rect2 = d3.select('rect#test2').node().getBoundingClientRect();
console.log('Rect 2: { top: ' + (rect2.top-svgXY.top) + ', left: ' + (rect2.left-svgXY.left) + '}');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>


<svg width="300" height="200">

  <rect x="20" y="40" fill="red" width="100" height="40" id="test1"></rect>
  <rect x="20" y="40" fill="green" width="100" height="40" transform="translate(40, 30)" id="test2"></rect>
</svg>
```

Or if you're using **jQuery**, you can get the position by using `$('rect#test1').position()`.

Hope this helps.

**Edit:**
`body` had a **margin** of 8px by default and hence `x` was equal to `28`. I've added the CSS and check out the snippet now.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I need the actual x and y co-ordinates of the element, which is not the case above. In your example of Rect 1, x is 28 but it should be 20, and y is 48 but it should be 40.

Comment: @Bluefire `body` had a margin of 8px by default. I just removed that and you can see the actual co-ordinates now.

Comment: I think you missed the point: I want the x- and y-coordinates of the element relative to the svg.

Comment: Yes I did. My bad. Anyway, my suggestion is to use the `getBoundingClientRect()` function (which you can play around with) to get the actual coordinates. (Btw I've edited the post to calculate the relative position by applying the same to the SVG as well).